# test a function called twice in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I have the following function which is called twice

```
def func():
    i=2
    while i
       call_me("abc")
       i-=1
```

I need to test this function whether it is called twice. Below test case test's if it called at all/many times with given arguments.

```
@patch('call_me')
def test_func(self,mock_call_me):
    self.val="abc"
    self.assertEqual(func(),None)
    mock_call_me.assert_called_with(self.val)
```

I want to write a test case where  "mock_call_me.assert_called_once_with("abc")" raises an assertion error so that i can show it is called twice.

I don't know whether it is possible or not.Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.Mock.call_count

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
@patch('call_me')
def test_func(self,mock_call_me):
  self.assertEqual(func(),None)
  self.assertEqual(mock_call_me.call_count, 2)
```

Answer (score 60):

You can even check parameters passed to each call:

```
from mock import patch, call

@patch('call_me')
def test_func(self, mock_call_me):
    self.val="abc"
    self.assertEqual(func(),None)
    mock_call_me.assert_has_calls([call(self.val), call(self.val)])
```

Comment: This method will still pass even if `mock_call_me` has been called more than twice. If you'd like to assert parameters and number of calls, make sure to also validate call-count using `self.assertEqual(mock_call_me.call_count, 2)` as mentioned above.

Comment: I combined both methods to validate that it was called with specific parameters and that it was only called twice:

`mock_call_me.assert_has_calls([call(self.val1), call(self.val2)])`
`self.assertEqual(mock_call_me.call_count, 2)`

Answer (score 7):

```
@patch('call_me')
def test_func(self,mock_call_me):
    self.assertEqual(func(),None)
    assert mock_call_me.call_count == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that if you use flexmock then you can just write it this way:

`flexmock(call_me).should_receive('abc').once()`
`flexmock(call_me).should_receive('abc').twice()`

Link: http://has207.github.io/flexmock/